# Alternatives to corn syrup sugar

Tags: sugar, corn

I have just brewed my first batch of beer and after reading the booster pack ingredients to add to the Cooper's tin I see there is mainly corn syrup as an ingredient, I would like to use a healthier alternative such as organic raw sugar, is this possible? Or could someone please advise me on other sugars to use. Much appreciated.

Lance

Answer (score 2):

Corn syrup (glucose solution) is a perfectly adequate and "healthy" addition for brewing purposes. If one didn't want to use corn syrup then one could use dried glucose (brewers sugar) or dried sucrose(table sugar) or liquid invert sugar (golden syrup). One can use candied sugar and any form of "organic" raw sugar  or even molasses/treacle - but be warned the final taste may change.  Or one could just use more malt extract which is mostly maltose and malto-dextrins. Using a can of Coopers malt extract would be perfect and one could forego the "more refined" sugars altogether. The sugar is only used because it is cheap and plentiful and beer needs something like 3Kg of carbs per 24l/5gal - and the usual Coopers kit tin contains 1.7Kg.

Comment: Great thanks heaps for the information much appreciated.